# QGIS print composer won't export map with base layer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.4

I have a map that when I try and export it from the print composer to a jpeg, I get the map but the base layer has tiles with "map data not yet available". If I print from composer, it prints correctly.

Any ideas? I'm stumped! I'm using the USGS scanned topos as the base layer and have had this work fine in the past, so I assume it is a setting somewhere I have changed.

QGIS 2.4

Comment: Which base layer? Is this through a web service? There are issues with exporting maps from QGIS using OpenLayers basemaps, ie. Google Maps, etc.

Comment: It was the USGS Scanned maps. Turns out if I use the google compatible one it does not work, but if I use the non-google compatible one, it works. (http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml)

Comment: Glad you got it to work!!!